# How to make responsive thumbnail?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a question about "RESPONSIVE THUMBNAIL".

I use Wordpress and this [(click)](http://www.samgyoyu.com) is my site. You can check it.

My Posts thumbnail is look like this ↓

[image: Q1]

I have 4 thumbnail. It's 300px 300px (square). And It's made by this code ↓

```
/* =============================================================================
   LAYOUT
   ========================================================================== */
.wrapper {margin:0 auto}

.grids{margin-left:-30px}
[class*="grid-"]{display:inline;float:left;margin-left:30px}
.grid-12{margin-right:0}

/* Grid 1080px */
.wrapper{width:100%}
.grid-1{width:60px}.grid-2{width:150px}.grid-3{width:240px}.grid-4{width:300px}.grid-5{width:420px}.grid-6{width:510px}.grid-7{width:600px}.grid-8{width:690px}.grid-9{width:780px}.grid-10{width:870px}.grid-11{width:960px}.grid-12{width:1030px}

/* Grid 960px (mediaqueries) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.wrapper{width:100%}
.grid-1{width:50px}.grid-2{width:130px}.grid-3{width:210px}.grid-4{width:290px}.grid-5{width:370px}.grid-6{width:450px}.grid-7{width:530px}.grid-8{width:610px}.grid-9{width:690px}.grid-10{width:770px}.grid-11{width:850px}.grid-12{width:910px}
}

/* Grid 800px (mediaqueries) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 959px) {
.wrapper{width:100%}
.grids{margin-left:-20px}
[class*="grid-"]{margin-left:20px}
.grid-1{width:40px}.grid-2{width:100px}.grid-3{width:160px}.grid-4{width:220px}.grid-5{width:280px}.grid-6{width:340px}.grid-7{width:400px}.grid-8{width:460px}.grid-9{width:520px}.grid-10{width:580px}.grid-11{width:640px}.grid-12{width:680px}
}

/* Grid lt 800px / Mobile (mediaqueries) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.wrapper{width:100%}
.grids,
[class*="grid-"]{width:100%;margin-left:0;margin-right:0}
html{font-size:1.125em /* Make text slightly larger for smaller devices to improve readability. */}
body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none}
}
```

You can see /* Grid 1080px */ and grid-4{width:300px}.

And I use this code too.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),’thumbnail’ );
     echo '<img width="100%" src="' . $image_src[0] . '">';
}
?>
```

**This is my question :**

How to make responsive thumbnail?

My thumbnail is resize only at 1080px, 960px, 800px, etc.

I would like to make my thumbnail always responsive. In any pixel, any device. Like this site [(click)](http://www.herschelsupply.com).

You can see that site's thumbnail is always reponsive. It's really great!

Please help me! Thanks:)

Comment: Your site is using some plugin to apply the style via JavaScript. You might have to disable it and then add your CSS.

Comment: @Teknotica Hi, Thank you for your comment. Yes, I used it. I disable it now! Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with max-width and width:100%, for example:

```
.myResponsiveThumbnail {
    width:100%;
    max-width:300px;
}
```

You can apply this a several times in your media queries, and just change the max-width to whatever width it can be on his max.

Comment: Hi Arko, Thank you for your answer. It's great! I have one more question. Can I make my thumbnail responsive irrespective of monitor size? Like [link](http://www.herschelsupply.com) this site and my slider? No use media queries?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with this question?

Comment: I mean, (sorry for my poor English) If you checked That site, You can see the thumbnail resize on all size of monitor. If you change your browser size little smaller or bigger, you can check it.

Comment: They use `width: 100%;` as well to their thumbnails. The parent is for example `width: 25%`, what makes the image always stay `width: 100%` to the parent. If you resize the window, it becomes smaller automatically. Its quite the same as my answer above.

Comment: Thank you! And sorry to confuse you. So I have to make media queries (or paste to that grid)? Or I just past that code to style.css?

Comment: You can paste this code into your style.css, just make sure the classname is correct to your images.